# I need help "matching" and indirecting" in python

Tags: python, excel

I have a long array such as:

```
array1= [
[300, "Document1"],
[301, "Document2"],
[302, "Document3"],
[303, "Document4"],
[304, "Document5"],
[305, "Document6"],
[306, "Document7"],
[307, "Document8"],
[308, "Document9"],]
```

and then I am given a shorter array such as:

```
array2 = [301, 305, 306]
```

What I need is to "match" the numbers in array 2 and have an array output that gives me:

```
outputarray = [Document2, Document6, Document7]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
output = [j for i, j in array1 if i in array2]
```

This should work.

Comment: So I added: output = []
output.append[j for i, j in array1 if i in array2]
this just returns [ [ ] ].

Comment: Just use `output = [j for i, j in array1 if i in array2]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might want to keep your data in a dict, because it is a mapping of numbers to document names, and `dict`s are used for such mappings:

```
data_in_a_dict = dict(array1)
# {300: 'Document1', 301: 'Document2', 302: 'Document3', 303: 'Document4',
#  304: 'Document5', 305: 'Document6', 306: 'Document7', 307: 'Document8',
#  308: 'Document9'}
```

Then, it becomes easy to extract data from it:

```
outputarray = [data_in_a_dict[key] for key in array2]
# ['Document2', 'Document6', 'Document7']
```

Comment: @Plunge What kind of error? I just copied-and-pasted your `array1` and `array2` and then copied-and-pasted my two lines. There are no errors.

Comment: if some key in `array2` is not in `array1`, this causes a KeyError when you try to access `data_in_a_dict[key]`.

Comment: @AshishAcharya Yes. That is the correct thing to happen in my opinion. If there is need to allow missing keys in `array2`, that can easily be put into the code, but otherwise, it is likely an error in the input data, for which a `KeyError` is the most appropriate result.